# openpose compilation tells undefined reference to cv::VideoCapture::VideoCapture(cv::String const&)

Tags: opencv, caffe

I have comipled caffe with GPU disabled,then

```
cp caffe/build/Makefile openpose/Makefile.conf
```

run

```
 make all -j 6
```

got these errors:

```
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /path/to/caffe/build
CXX/LD -o ._release/examples/tutorial_thread/1_openpose_read_and_display.bin
._release/lib/libopenpose.so: undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::VideoCapture(cv::String const&)'
._release/lib/libopenpose.so: undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::set(int, double)'
._release/lib/libopenpose.so: undefined reference to `op::renderPartAffinityFieldGpu(float*, op::PoseModel, cv::Size_<int> const&, float const*, cv::Size_<int> const&, float, int, float)'
._release/lib/libopenpose.so: undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::release()'
._release/lib/libopenpose.so: undefined reference to `op::renderBodyPartsGpu(float*, op::PoseModel, cv::Size_<int> const&, float const*, cv::Size_<int> const&, float, float)'
._release/lib/libopenpose.so: undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::operator>>(cv::Mat&)'
```

can't find opencv,and I compiled latest opencv 3.2-dev from source,all opencv programs(both c++ and python) worked,so why cann't openpose find opencv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caffe recognized opencv actually,those reference are method that were discarded  in opencv3.2 ,but are available in opencv 3.1.0 or earlier version.i had the same problem while installing 3.2 and eventualy downgrading to 3.1.0 solved the issue for me,[here](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/10/24/ubuntu-16-04-how-to-install-opencv/) is a nice guide to install opencv 3.1.0 and according to

[this](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/1603) discussion,it seems that the standard is to support opencv that are available in Ubuntu sources and i think you can't install opencv3.2 through apt-get by now,only need to build from source

Comment: Thanks,I have downgraded to 3.1,and uncommet:                       CPU_ONLY := 1
OPENCV_VERSION := 3                                                                                         opencv related error gone,but these errors:   
  ._release/lib/libopenpose.so: undefined reference to `op::renderPartAffinityFieldGpu(float*, op::PoseModel, cv::Size_<int> const&, float const*, cv::Size_<int> const&, float, int, float)'                          still exist.

Comment: i think it has to do with openpose,i guess you have to do to the same process by checking wich version of openpose works with opencv and downgrade or upgrade to the new version,these type errors indicates that openpose implemented some of the functions that are not available in your current opencv..and you may also disable/comment #USE CUDNN in case you are using CPU only since when you enable it...some function will do some cuda assertion checking that will always fail since you re not using CUDA

Comment: Thanks,I guess it is the compilation of examples caused these errors due to they don't know CUDA has been disabled,so they still try to use CUDA,and I just don't know how to remove these example from compilation

Comment: i guess you have to hack abit your Makefile(not makefile.config) and comment examples  EXAMPLE_SRCS := $(shell find examples -name "*.cpp") and remove example from NONGEN_CXX_SRCS := $(shell find \
 src/$(PROJECT) \
 include/$(PROJECT) \
 examples \
 -name "*.cpp" -or -name "*.hpp" -or -name "*.cu" -or -name "*.cuh") in this file ,not sure if it will work out....but you might give it a try https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose/blob/master/Makefile#L88

Answer (score 1):

With CMake installer (recommended one):

This error should never occur with the CMake installer, so I would recommend you to use the recommended installer.

With Makefile installer (deprecated one):

`I have compiled caffe with GPU disabled`:
You cannot disable GPU for OpenPose (nor the Caffe that OpenPose will use). I am sorry but the CPU code is not finished at all (and not expected to be finished at the moment given the very slow speed). You will have to use CUDA + cuDNN.

In order to fix the OpenCV not found problem, you need to enable in both Makefile.conf files (the one from OpenPose and Caffe), the use OpenCV 3 flag.