# Caffe build fails repeatedly

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, caffe

I am trying to compile the software [OpenPose](https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose/blob/master/doc/installation.md) on an Ubuntu 14 machine. The installation script installs Caffe. While installing Caffe, I get the following error message:

```
CXX tools/upgrade_net_proto_text.cpp
CXX/LD -o .build_release/tools/upgrade_net_proto_text.bin
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `cv::imread(cv::String const&, int)'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `cv::imencode(cv::String const&, cv::_InputArray const&, std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&)'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `cv::imdecode(cv::_InputArray const&, int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [.build_release/tools/upgrade_net_proto_text.bin] Error 1
```

From [here](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/3700), I have tried running `ldconfig`, I use OpenCV 3.2.0, so I have uncommented that in the makefile. I have also tried updating the OpenCV path in `~/.bashrc` but I am not sure if I did it correctly. I did:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

After each of these steps, I ran the install script again but it fails with the same error message (shown above) every time.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't seen anyone so far who successfully installed caffe with openCV 3.2.0,i faced the same problem and what i did was to downgrade to OpenCV 3.1.Another problem that came along was missing modules that are in open_contrib that you should install along opencv,i d refer you to this answer also related to OpenPose [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44236198/openpose-compilation-tells-undefined-reference-to-cvvideocapturevideocapture/44237793#44237793)

Comment: I had installed opencv_contrib. But this information about incompatibility with openCV 3.2.0 is new. I'll try 3.1.